# R rename all columns with regex

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I messy column names that have the following format: column name is in English, followed by a slash(/), followed by a same word in French with the year. for example

`CSD Code / Code de la SDR 2011`,
`Education / Scolarité 2011`,
`Labour Force Activity / Activité sur le marché du travail 2011`

is there a tidyverse friendly solution that will let me rename all the columns by removing everything after the slash(/) but keep the year. for example:
`CSD Code 2011`,
`Education 2011`,
`Labour Force Activity 2011`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression. With the sample data:

```
x <- c("CSD Code / Code de la SDR 2011", 
        "Education / Scolarité 2011", 
        "Labour Force Activity / Activité sur le marché du travail 2011")
```

You can use the tidyverse package `stringr` and get

```
stringr::str_replace(x, " / \\D*(?= \\d+$)", "")
# [1] "CSD Code 2011"             
# [2] "Education 2011"            
# [3] "Labour Force Activity 2011"
```

The expression looks for a space and a slash and removes all the non-digit characters afterward leaving just the digits at the end.

You can use that with the `dplyr::rename_with` for column names

```
my_data %>% 
  rename_with(~stringr::str_replace(., " / \\D*(?= \\d+$)", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the part of the string that you want to keep with capture groups.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rename_with(~sub('(.*)/.*?(\\d+)', '\\1\\2', .))
```

Using data from @MrFlick -

```
sub('(.*)/.*?(\\d+)', '\\1\\2', x)
#[1] "CSD Code 2011"              "Education 2011"            
#[3] "Labour Force Activity 2011"
```